$41$ divides $2^{20}-1$
This is my first modular arithmetic proof so I'm checking to see if it works:
To begin, I want to show that this is true:
\begin{align*}
2^{20}-1 \equiv 0 \pmod{41} \\
2^{20} \equiv 1 \pmod{41}
\end{align*}
Now, I note this congruence with the power of $2$ and then do the identity "if $a \equiv b \pmod n$ then $a^k \equiv b^k \pmod n$"
\begin{align*}
2^5 \equiv -9 \pmod{41} \\
\left(2^5\right)^4 \equiv (-9)^4 \pmod{41} 
\end{align*}
Now, I note another congruence with the power of $-9$:
\begin{align*}
(-9)^2 \equiv -1 \pmod{41} \\
(-9)^4 \equiv 1 \pmod{41}
\end{align*}
I can put these together because ``if $a \equiv b \pmod n$ and $b \equiv c \pmod n$, then $a \equiv c \pmod n$"
\begin{align*}
2^{20} \equiv (-9)^4 \pmod{41} \\
\equiv 1 \pmod{41} 
\end{align*}
And I get what I wanted to show that was true.
Although this is different than the book, I think this is still correct? At least, I think I'm following the basic properties correctly.

Yes, your proof is correct. You have computed $2^{20} \pmod{41}$ efficiently using a method similar to exponentiation by squaring. By the way, your question title should read "$41$ divides $2^{20} - 1$".

@TobErnack I fixed the title. And "nice" in how this is correct. Thanks

You might get interested in Euler's criterion; also $2^7=128\equiv5\bmod41$ and $2^3=8$ so $2^{10}\equiv40\equiv-1\bmod41$

For a solution-verification question to be on topic you must specify precisely which step in the proof you question, and why so. This site is not meant to be used as a proof checking machine.

i.e. $\ (2^5)^4 \equiv (-3^2)^4 \equiv (3^4)^2 \equiv (-1)^2\equiv 1 \ \ $
